How to transform a bivariate polynomial P(x,y) into a multivariate one H(S1(x,y),S2(x,y),..,Sn(x,y)) knowing that such representation exists?
How can I transform a bivariate polynomial P(x,y) into a multivariate one H(S1(x,y),S2(x,y),..,Sn(x,y)) knowing that such representation exists? Let me provide a specific example:
I know that

f(x,y)=x^4+2x^3y+2x^3-2x^2y^2+6x^2y+6x^2+2xy^3+6xy^2+12xy+8x+y^4+2y^3+6y^2+8y+4

can be written as

g((x+y),(x-y),(1+x),(1-x),(1+y),(1-y),(1-xy))

However, the transformation is simply too complicated to make by hand. I tried all kinds of simplification functions available in Matlab and Mathematica for symbolic expressions but they were of no help either. Is there a smart way to go about this? Or perhaps a software/function I can use?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

When the degree of $H$ is not too large you can just compute the monomials in $S_1, \dots, S_n$ up to a certain degree and search for a linear combination giving $f$. This would just be linear algebra. In your case this seems unnecessary since you can just write $x =S_3(x,y)-1$ and $y =S_5(x,y)-1$ (of course many other choices are possible).

Thank you. Do you mind dumbing it down for me a little? How do I do that exactly? Please bear in mind that I studied some math but I don't have a math degree.

When the smallest possible degree of $H$ is not too large a simple brute force method is to compute the monomials in $S_1$, ...,$S_n$ up to a certain degree and search for a linear combination giving $f$. So you make the ansatz
$$ H(s_1,...,s_n) = \sum_{i_1+...+i_n \leq d} a_{i_1,...,i_n} \, s_1^{i_1} \, \cdots \, s_n^{i_n} $$
for some sufficiently large degree $d$ and then solve the linear equation $H(S_1(x,y),...,S_n(x,y)) = f(x,y)$ for the (not necessarily unique) coefficients $a_{i_1,...,i_n}$.
Since your example is very simple let's instead look at the example $f(x,y) = 2 \, x^2 \, y^3 + y^2+y^6$ with $S_1(x,y) = x^2+y$, $S_2(x,y) = x^2-y$, $S_3(x,y) = x^2+y^3$. For $d=2$ our ansatz reads
$$
\begin{align*}
H(s_1,s_2,s_3) = \hphantom{+}&a_{0,0,0} \\
+ &a_{1,0,0} \, s_1 + a_{0,1,0} \, s_2 + a_{0,0,1} \, s_3 \\
+ &a_{2,0,0} \, s_1^2 + a_{0,2,0} \, s_2^2 + a_{0,0,2} \, s_3^2 \\
+ &a_{1,1,0} \, s_1 \, s_2 + a_{1,0,1} \, s_1 \, s_3 + a_{0,1,1} \, s_2 \, s_3
\end{align*}
$$
and comparing coefficients we obtain the equation
$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{0,0,0} \\
a_{1,0,0} \\
a_{0,1,0} \\
a_{0,0,1} \\
a_{2,0,0} \\
a_{0,2,0} \\
a_{0,0,2} \\
a_{1,1,0} \\
a_{1,0,1} \\
a_{0,1,1} \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
\, .
\end{align*}
$$
This has the unique solution $H(s_1,s_2,s_3) = s_3^2-s_1\, s_2$. For $d \geq 3$ the solution is not unique anymore (because $4\, S_1+4 \, S_2-8 \, S_3+3 \, S_1 \, S_2^2 - 3 \, S_1^2 \, S_2 + S_1^3-S_2^3 = 0$).
